# How to apply a activated feature/workflow to a list

Tags: workflow, solution-package

I have created a global workflow and added it to a SP 2010 site as a solution (which I have activated), but when I go to apply this workflow to my list/library the new workflow template is not in the list of possible workflows that I can select from.

Once I have added a workflow as a Solution to a site, how do I apply it to the list that I want to run the workflow against?

Thanks

Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you follow the procedure and created a "**Globally Reusable Workflow**" and not just a "**Reusable Workflow**" (just to be sure - have a look at the procedure here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70867/Reusable-and-Globally-Reusable-Workflows-in-ShareP) in addition to ensure in Site Collection is activated also open the Top-Level site via SharePoint 2010 Designer and under the Workflows node you should see in the Category "**Globally Reusable Workflows**" along with others (might depend according to your settings), such as Approval, Collect Feedback, etc.

Comment: Is the Site Collection another feature/solution that needs to be activated. In the work enviroment I'm in I can't use SharePoint designer to look at anything except MySite, so I can't see the main site in SP Designer.

Comment: you should at least see it at the Site Collection Features level

Comment: I've looked at the Site Collection Features level and my workflow is not in this list. Not sure if the administrator for the main site has blocked this

Comment: "Blocking it" - practically means not deployed the .wsp package

Answer (score 0):

`Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Under Site Actions Group click Manage Site Features ->` Then activate that workflow

Comment: OK, I've done that, but my workflow is still not accessible as a template in the workflow page, when I'm trying to setup a new workflow? Is there another step I need to do?

Comment: Activate your solution in the top-level site through a sharepoint administrator account, and then activating that feature on your site which i think is what you've done already... so the first step you havent done yet.... i think :)\